# IBM Business Process Framework with IBM FileNet 5.2

Tags: filenet-p8, content-platform-engine

We are considering to migrate our FileNet system from 4.5 to 5.2, but not sure if applications running on top of BPF could work.
Did anyone try to make BPF application run on FileNet CPE 5.2?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, BPF is officially supported on FileNet 5.2. BPF 4.1 with fixpack 009 or above is required. See [IBM FileNet P8 5.2 Related Requirements](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27013654&aid=1) for more details.